# Keep python script running on background and reopen it if it dies

Tags: python, windows

I am kinda new to python, so I am still getting the hang of it. I need a way to have a script running, constantly checking for the time, that opens as soons as the computer is turned on and automatically restarts if it dies or is killed.

Comment: looks like you are in need of a library like celery

Comment: I have looked into it and it seems like it needs a broker, since you said a library *like* celery, I'd guess it has similar alternatives? Is there any without the broker requirement?

Comment: you can run it as daemon process but restarting the process when it fails might not be possible without something like celery

Comment: What you need is an external program that is launched at start time, starts your Python script, wait for it to terminate and if that happens restarts it. Optionaly, it could intercept the windows shutting down event to signal the script that is should terminate, if it makes sense. Celery may be a solution, but you can easily roll your own. Unfortunately, this question is currently too broad.

Comment: I have thought of that, but didn't quite think of a way to implement it. I could make another python script, but I still don't know how it would open automatically when the computer is turned on